# What is wrong with this setChar statement?

Tags: java

What's wrong with this `setChar` statement:

```
setChar(stringArray, numLetterChange, charLetterChange);
```

`stringArray` is actually a char array, which originated as a string.  the `numLetterChange` variable is a number a user enters between 0 and 3 saying what letter they want to change in the array, and `charLetterChange` is the letter that they want to change it to.  Any answers will be greatly appreciated.

(ChangeOneLetter.jave:67:error:cannot find symbol) is the error i am receiving

Comment: it might help to see some code here.

Comment: show the real source.  Include source covering "stringArray is actually a char array, which originated as a string"

Answer (score 0):

The error message means exactly what it says: you are referencing a name that does not exist at that point in the code. It might be that you do not have a method `setChar` defined with exactly the argument signature you are using here. More likely, though, is that one (or more) of your variables has gone out of scope. Typical code that could cause this is:

```
try {
    int numLetterChange = . . . // get user input
    char charLetterChange = . . . // get more user input
} catch (IOException e) {
    // print error message
}
setChar(stringArray, numLetterChange, charLetterChange);
```

If you have constructs like this (whether using try/catch, or any other block structure), the solution is to move the declaration of the variable outside the block so it stays in scope after the block exits:

```
int numLetterChange;
char charLetterChange;
try {
    numLetterChange = . . . // get user input
    charLetterChange = . . . // get more user input
} catch (IOException e) {
    // print error message
}
setChar(stringArray, numLetterChange, charLetterChange);
```

Comment: In your example I think the compiler still complain that these variables might not be set, unless they are assigned values at declaration or in the `catch` (or if there's a `throw` in the `catch`).

Comment: @PaulBellora - Yes indeed, the compiler will complain about that. I wasn't trying to write complete code, just to make a point about variable scope. It's tempting to arbitrarily initialize variables to 0 (or some such) to avoid the error, but unless default values make sense it's better to see the complaint. Code should be organized to either definitely assign a value or to avoid executing code that depends on a definite value having been assigned.

Comment: I think we're on the same page about organizing code. When I said complain, I just meant it won't compile if a beginner copies it verbatim.

Comment: @PaulBellora - Agreed. Of course, a verbatim copy also won't compile because of the `. . .` in two place. :)